# Comparison of values in Dataframes with different size

Tags: pandas, conditional-statements, comparison, size

I have a DataFrame in which I want to compare the speed of certain IDs at different conditions.
Boundary conditions:

1. IDs do not have to be represented in every condition,
2. ID is not represented in every condition with the same frequency.

My goal is to assign whether the speed remained

- larger (speed > than speed in CondA +10%),
- smaller ((speed < than speed in CondA -10%)) or
- the same (speed < than speed in CondA +10%) & (speed > than speed in CondA -10%))

depending on the condition.

The data

```
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd

    data1 = {
         'ID' : [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5],
         'Condition' : ['Cond_A', 'Cond_A', 'Cond_A', 'Cond_A', 'Cond_A', 'Cond_A','Cond_A','Cond_A', ],
         'Speed' : [1.2, 1.05, 1.2, 1.3, 1.0, 0.85, 1.1, 0.85],
         }
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
    
       
    data2 = {
         'ID' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
         'Condition' : ['Cond_B', 'Cond_B', 'Cond_B', 'Cond_B', 'Cond_B', 'Cond_B' ],
         'Speed' : [0.8, 0.55, 0.7, 1.15, 1.2, 1.4],
         }
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
    
    data3 = {
         'ID' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 6],
         'Condition' : ['Cond_C', 'Cond_C', 'Cond_C', 'Cond_C', 'Cond_C' ],
         'Speed' : [1.8, 0.99, 1.7, 131, 0.2, ],
         }
    df3 = pd.DataFrame(data3)
    lst_of_dfs = [df1,df2, df3]
     
    # creating a Dataframe object 
    data = pd.concat(lst_of_dfs)
```

My goal is to archive a result like this

```
   Condition  ID    Speed   Category
0     Cond_A   1    1.150   NaN
1     Cond_A   2    1.300   NaN
2     Cond_A   3    0.925   NaN
3     Cond_A   4    1.100   NaN
4     Cond_A   5    0.850   NaN
5     Cond_B   1    0.800   faster
6     Cond_B   2    0.550   slower
7     Cond_B   3    0.700   slower
8     Cond_B   4    1.150   equal
...
```

**My attempt:**

1. Calculate average of speed for each ID per condition

```
    data = data.groupby(["Condition", "ID"]).mean()["Speed"].reset_index()
```

2. Definition of thresholds. Assuming I want to realize thresholds up to 10 percent around the CondA-Values

```
    threshold_upper = data.loc[(data.Condition == 'CondA')]['Speed'] + (data.loc[(data.Condition == 'CondA')]['Speed']*10/100) 
    threshold_lower = data.loc[(data.Condition == 'CondA')]['Speed'] - (data.loc[(data.Condition == 'CondA')]['Speed']*10/100)
```

3. Mapping strings 'faster', 'equal', 'slower' based on condition using numpy select.

```
conditions = [
    (data.loc[(data.Condition == 'CondB')]['Speed'] >  threshold_upper),  #check whether Speed of each ID in CondB is faster than Speed in CondA+10% 
    (data.loc[(data.Condition == 'CondC')]['Speed'] >  threshold_upper),    #check whether Speed of each ID in CondC is faster than Speed in CondA+10%
    ((data.loc[(data.Condition == 'CondB')]['Speed'] <  threshold_upper) &  (data.loc[(data.Condition == 'CondB')]['Speed'] >  threshold_lower)), #check whether Speed of each ID in CondB is slower than Speed in CondA+10% AND faster than Speed in CondA-10%
    ((data.loc[(data.Condition == 'CondC')]['Speed'] <  threshold_upper) &  (data.loc[(data.Condition == 'CondC')]['Speed'] >  threshold_lower)), #check whether Speed of each ID in CondC is slower than Speed in CondA+10% AND faster than Speed in CondA-10%
    (data.loc[(data.Condition == 'CondB')]['Speed'] <  threshold_upper),  #check whether Speed of each ID in CondB is slower than Speed in CondA-10%
    (data.loc[(data.Condition == 'CondC')]['Speed'] <  threshold_upper),    #check whether Speed of each ID in CondC is faster than Speed in CondA-10%
    ]
    
values = [
    'faster',
    'faster',
     'equal', 
     'equal',
     'slower',
     'slower'
      ]
    
    
data['Category'] = np.select(conditions, values)
```

Produces this error: <ValueError: Length of values (0) does not match length of index (16)>

My data frames unfortunately have a different length (since not all IDs performed all trials to each condition). I appreciate any hint. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want compare the speed with average speed (+ the mentioned threshold)of the group( condition + id )?

Comment: I want to compare the average speed of each ID in condition B or C compared to the average speed of the specific ID in Condition A +/- threshold. E.g.: Condition A is my normal speed and is measured 3 times. Then I am getting blindfolded and my speed is measured two times. I want to compare the difference between the averaged speeds (my ID - unimpeded vs blindfolded)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Dataframe created

data
    ID  Condition   Speed
0   1   Cond_A  1.20
1   1   Cond_A  1.05
2   1   Cond_A  1.20
```

```
# Reset the index
data = data.reset_index(drop=True)

# Creating based on ID
data['group'] = data.groupby(['ID']).ngroup()

# Creating functions which returns the upper and lower limit of speed

def lowlimit(x):
    return x[x['Condition']=='Cond_A'].Speed.mean() * 0.9

def upperlimit(x):
    return x[x['Condition']=='Cond_A'].Speed.mean() * 1.1

# Calculate the upperlimit and lowerlimit for the groups
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['ul'] = data.groupby('group').apply(lambda x: upperlimit(x))
df['ll'] = data.groupby('group').apply(lambda x: lowlimit(x))

# reseting the index
# So that we can merge the values of 'group' column
df = df.reset_index() 

# Merging the data and df dataframe

data_new = pd.merge(data,df,on='group',how='left')

data_new
    ID  Condition   Speed   group   ul  ll
0   1   Cond_A  1.20    0   1.2650  1.0350
1   1   Cond_A  1.05    0   1.2650  1.0350
2   1   Cond_A  1.20    0   1.2650  1.0350
3   2   Cond_A  1.30    1   1.4300  1.1700
```

Now we have to apply the conditions

```
data_new.loc[(data_new['Speed'] >= data_new['ul']) & (data_new['Condition'] != 'Cond_A'),'Category'] = 'larger'
data_new.loc[(data_new['Speed'] <= data_new['ll']) & (data_new['Condition'] != 'Cond_A'),'Category'] = 'smaller'
data_new.loc[(data_new['Speed'] < data_new['ul']) & (data_new['Speed'] > data_new['ll']) & (data_new['Condition'] != 'Cond_A'),'Category'] = 'Same'
```

Here is the output

[image]

You can drop the other columns now, if you want
`data_new = data_new.drop(columns=['group','ul','ll'])`

Comment: A very elegant solution using the df.loc method. Thank you very much.